# Css custom shape button

Tags: html, css, button, shapes

How do I make a custom shape button like this.
example: http://www.dennispkramer.com/index.html
I mean the button saying 'blog' and 'about'.

Comment: open the website in chrome, right click on the button, and click 'inspect element'. That should give some idea

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual button is a block, like normal.

[image]

However, they've added `#nav-mask` which looks like this:

[image]

Giving the illusion the buttons are like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those are not custom shapes. There is a mask behind the logo, in front of the menu items. There are some CSS tricks to create custom shapes like triangle, but for real custom shapes i would suggest to use SVG.